# Count Total issued per month using LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

I'm doing a sample project where it counts the total issues per month that is to be displayed in a bar graph..

Here is my working SQL query

```
SELECT 
 SUM(CASE datepart(month,D_ISSUE) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jan',
 SUM(CASE datepart(month,D_ISSUE) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Feb',
 so on...
FROM EMP_MEMOS
```

Can someone help me transpose this SQL Query into a LinQ code. i'm still trying to understand how it works

Here is my code so far, but i still can't get it to work.

```
public ActionResult MonthCount()
{
    var Monthly = (from f in db.EMP_MEMOS
                  group f by new { month = f.D_ISSUE, year = f.D_ISSUE } into g
                  orderby g.Key.year
                  select new
                  {
                      dt = string.Format("{0}/{1}", g.Key.month, g.Key.year),


                  }).ToList();

    return Json(new { result = Monthly }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got the answer, gonna share it here:

```
       public ActionResult CountMonth()
        {
            var memo = from t in db.EMP_MEMOS
                        select new
                        {
                             t.D_ISSUE.Value.Month,
                             t.D_ISSUE.Value.Year
                        };
            var res = from s in memo
                      group s by new { s.Year, s.Month } into g
                      select new
                      {
                          Period = g.Key,
                          MemoCount = g.Count(),
                      };
            return Json(new { result = res }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```